# Custom form borders

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a theme for Valentines day on my site and wondered if there is a possibility to make custom form borders e.g. a heart? Of course, I can place an image where needed but that's too much hard-coding.

Why I do not want hard-coding is also because I have dynamic content generation with photos (though, fixed size) and a small text, and I don't want that something goes wrong.

So, is there a way?

Comment: This might be interesting: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: @Kroltan Wow, such a fast answer! Thank you! :)

Comment: put it on answer so this question can marked as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) has an excellent article about custom shapes using only HTML and CSS, which includes a heart shape. The heart shape was suggested by [Nicolas Gallagher](http://nicolasgallagher.com/):

```
#heart {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
}
#heart:before,
#heart:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 50px;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 80px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
         -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
            transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
#heart:after {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
         -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
            transform-origin :100% 100%;
}
```

As interesting as this may sound, it uses only one element!

Answer (score 0):

This is a great post!

Article above is fantastic.

If the content you'd like within the border is a fixed size, or if there is a very specific heart shape you want without playing with the code, another pretty safe option is to use pseudo elements to add a image border.

Something along these lines:

```
/* content */

.content {

  position: relative;

}

/* heart wrapper */

.content:before {

  background: url(image/heart.png);
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

}
```